# No Linux OS will install

Tags: 14.04, grub2

To my dismay, I have attempted to install several Linux systems in the past month. I have tried Oz Unity's Star Sapphire 3 times now without success. The first time it installed without issue, restarted after removing cd just fine,but after updating and trying to launch Steam and install Steam games. On reboot, it hung overnight and went to a black screen with lots of errors.

I restarted and chose the recovery option but nothing worked and fdsk did not fix it, it hung overnight at 2%. I decided to reinstall, installation hung and went to 's to skip or m for manual recovery', manual recovery just gave more error messaes and I did not feel confident to tackle this.

So I tried another install, this time I wiped the hard drive with Webroot System Eraser and it seemed to be going a thousand times quicker but hung at install after a couple of error messages about Glib while copying files: 'Source ID 3498 etc was not found when attempting to remove it'. I did select Erase all files and install at the splash screen as there was no other option for install (even though I had wiped the drive).

After reading a post about Steam games not working in Star Sapphire I decided to try Ubuntu 14.04.1 as several forums suggested Steam works in Ubuntu. It seemed to install fine but on reboot I get a black screen with copious process error messages. No Grub. System Rescue Cd provided no fixes.

The last attempted reinstall today with Ubuntu 14.04.1 in UEFI, the install process went all the way to restart, I tried to install updated while configuring hardware and that failed, at the prompt I removed the cd and press enter, then a black screen for ages, then appeared '[195.952592] systemd-udevd (348): timeout 'mtp-probe/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3 1 4', a very, very long delay then, Purple Ubuntu loading screen for another very long time, then black, it then switched off. When I switched it back on a purple boarder appeared around the edge then black - nothing. I hard powered it off and back on, black screen, no grub.

I am at my wits end! I am desperate NOT to go back to Windows (it kept hanging after 20-30 mins after bootup) and want a Linux OS.

My system may have a lot to do with it but I also suspect the BIOS setting are not working. It is a 2013 (less than 2 years old) Medion Akoya with Windows 8 pre-installed (was as it has since been wiped). 
I have followed all the Ubuntu official guides for UEFI turning off 'Secure Boot' etc. I've tried changing boot type from UEFI to Dual to Legacy. I have promoted the boot sequence to CDROM.

Nothing is working and I feel like I have a $500 brick that used to be the center of our home entertainment.

Laptop: Medion Akoya E6232 (MD 99222) notebook
Processor: Intel 3rd gen Core i3 2.5GHz Intel Core i3-3120M
RAM: 4.00 GB
Intergrated Graphics Card: Intel HD 4000
Internal storage: 500GB

Answer (score 1):

Take a deep breath.

Generally problems like you're describing come from two areas

1. A corrupted system image on the installation media.  Check the checksum to avoid wailing and gnashing of teeth.  A corrupted image only leads to tears.
2. Hardware failure, or impending hardware failure.

If you have a *bona fide* image on a USB in the form of a LiveCD, and the LiveCD boots, and runs, use the tools on the LiveCD to verify the integrity of your hardware, and *pre-*setup your machine to accept the new system.

- Use **GParted** and partition it as you wish.  I have a personal preference to at least 3 partitions (swap partition equivalent to RAM size; `/`, a root partition 10-30GB, depending; and the rest of the space devoted to `/home`)

Typically,

- `/dev/sda1` = `/` (root)
- `/dev/sda2` = `/home`
- `/dev/sda`X = swap

The order and numerical sequence is more important the OCD you are.

Now, after you have partitioned and formatted this unknown harddrive, check and mark any `badblocks` that might give you a bad day.

- Open a terminal `<ctrl><alt><t>` at the same time, and enter `sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda > bad-blocks`

This goes over the drive and notes any 'bad blocks' and writes the information to a file `bad-blocks`  in the current working directory (on the LiveCD).

- While it's churning away this is a good time to check if the machine is overheating.  Granted it's subjective, but does it feel *hot*?  Are the vents clear and the feel/hear the fans blowing off the heat?
- Remove any *bad block* from future use via the `bad-blocks` file you have just finished creating `sudo fsck -t ext4 -l bad-blocks /dev/sda` changing the `ext4` to the format you laid down on the partitions.
- Run some of the memory tests available when as you boot up the LiveCD.  You don't have to run the whole series, but just let it run for 10 minutes to see if it throws an error. (If it does, then that's another matter.)  What you are looking for is a point of failure; image and hardware integrity, a sloppy USB connector...something that might suggest not everything is optimal for a carefree installation.

Everything passes?...the machine doesn't overheat, or spit up running from the LiveCD after running through its paces, and a test drive on the internet, or whatever?

Now, try an installation, using the **Something else** option, and place the system in your pre-defined partitions.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much, Nodak! I have hope now! Am giving it a go as I type. I have put the BIOS settings back to Dual boot (both UEFI and Legacy) as that was the last setting that was most successful (and the first try at installing).

What type of file system should /root be in? 

In G-parted it says it's fat32. I read elsewhere it should be ext2 (grub) or ext4 (grub2).

What is correct??

I have also installed Boot Repair just in case. I'm not sure if this will be of any assistance as Grub loads fine, it just hasn't progressed anywhere after that in previous installs.

Comment: G-parted has crashed. When I tried to update gparted is said there was no space left on disk. Am running the USB Live CD as advised.

Comment: Rather than *update* GParted, if GParted is crashing that would point more toward a corrupted image.  I don't know what *tool* you have on hand, but I'd recommend heading down this path https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: Partition format, to a degree, is a matter of preference and intended end use.  On a home machine, 99.44% of the time you can't go wrong with `ext4`.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemsExplained

Comment: I download a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.1 image and created a fresh LiveCD.  On boot, when the screen goes purple, hit `<Shift>` and then `<esc>`.  This gives you a boot menu.  3rd option down the list is the ability to check the integrity of the LiveCD.  Give that a go.  Obviously if it fails...start again.  If it doesn't fail...well, that's another kettle of fish.

Comment: I will add; there should be no reason to add anything to your LiveCD, at this point.  In the future, sure, maybe, but right now you are just looking for an install.  99.44% of the time an *off the shelf* LiveCD will do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still won't work. I'm trying another Webroot wipe. I have created an updated version of G-parted on a USB (the previous version had a know bug for crashing) and will try to partition again. I am downloading a fresh copy of Ubuntu. Can you advise how to check for hardware faults or issues? My BIOS/UEFI does not give me the option.

Comment: I have been able to verify via MD5SUM that my copy is identical.

Comment: So, are we having fun yet?  You are now looking for hardware problems.  From a LiveCD, from the terminal, find out what filesystems are on the drive with `df -T` They should automount.  Note the filesystem type and if your first partition is in fact a FAT32, `sudo umount /dev/sda1` to unmount the drive.  `sudo fsck.vfat -atvw /dev/sda1` to check.  The flags are: `-a` to automagically repair, `-t` for test for bad clusters, `v` is verbose, `w` writes the changes.  Go through every partition in a similar manner.

Comment: I'm speculating, but I think there is damage on your drive.  It might just be psychological, but even if it is not, it's not the end of the world.  If the fsck.vfat makes it through without spitting up, try the GParted plan of attack again.

Comment: I'm still speculating.... Since the image is clean, without seeing it, it appear there are some gremlins in your drive. Worse case, but not fatal is physical damage.  But it still spins.  It might be un-marked bad blocks, or just a tangled filesystem that flipped out GParted.  I don't know.  But the drive needs a fresh partition and filesystem. The only problem is, generally the more robust the tool, the more *skill* required, keeping from going wrong and damaging your own psyche. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html, if push comes to shove, and you have the stomach for it.

Comment: No, really, it'll be worth it.

Comment: Fun? My head is throbbing!!! G-parted was a little more work than advised. I didn't know which partition was logical or primary or how to set it up properly and NOTHING out in the interwebs clarifies how to partition an empty HDD! So frustrating! What I ended up doing was:                                                          /dev/sda1 = / (root) ext4 primary 10Gb
/dev/sda2 = /home  ext4   logical 470Gb
/dev/sdaX = swap          logical 4Gb                                           (I managed to calculate the size of each partition as advised).

Comment: Somehow I didn't make wherever the install packages go big enough... Can I change them from here? It at LEAST restarted, it hasn't done that since the first install. 1 month and 5 installs ago...

Comment: Ok, just to clarify `/dev/sdaX = swap logical 4Gb`, the **X** is a number, 3,4,5,etc.  `/dev/sdaX`, just means *un determined*...'whatever it might be'.  This is a glimpse of the *backend* of GParted. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/09/parted-command-examples/ It is made to be obtuse to develop a protective layer of scaring.

Comment: Yes.... I think so....

Comment: An overly simplistic analogy of partitions, and one that I use for my own understanding is a cardboard box.  The size of the box is the size of your drive.  Unless otherwise 99.44% of PC hard drives have an `msdos` partition table.  This table says, *You can have 4, and only 4, smaller boxes inside the big box* Those are called **primary**, but...but one of those boxes (primary partitions) can have a different box called an **extended** partition that can have up to 4 little boxes (logical partitions) inside of it without violating the 4 box rule for itself or the entire box.

Comment: Right... To be clear, are you saying that the swap partition should be MUCH bigger than 4gb if I have a 500gb laptop? I took your advice before literately to mean "swap partition equivalent to RAM size" my RAM is 3.7Gb therefore I made the swap eqivalent in size. And, can I change it from this point or do I need to unmount or go out of the os to change the partitions in G-parted via usb(g-parted iso)?

Comment: I'm saying `swap` should be any size you want.  A rule of thumb is that it should equal the RAM capacity of the machine.  If you want to `hibernate` the machine, yes.  If you don't, then maybe no so much.  If you're tight on space, skimp.  LiveCDs have none.  But 500GB you can spare 4GB even though you may never use it all.  The *number* thing was that your swap would be locate `/dev/sda3`, or `/dev/sda5`...or whatever. One is size, the other is location.  And, yes, devices are like humans, they don't like major operations done on them unless anaesthetized. Unmount.